# discord.py bot commands only get Context

Tags: python, discord.py

I just tested the syntax for discord.py and found something wrong.

`client` is `commands.Bot()` for the following 3 snippets of code:

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_permissions(manage_roles=True)
async def add_role(mes: discord.Message, member: discord.Member, role: discord.Role):
    print(mes)
    # input: ?add_role someone Tester
    # output: <discord.ext.commands.context.Context object at 0x03B2EF30>
```

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def exit(mes: discord.ext.commands.Context):
    print(mes)
    # input: ?exit
    # output: <discord.ext.commands.context.Context object at 0x03B2EF50>
```

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def ask(mes: discord.message.Message):
    print(mes)
    # input: ?ask
    # output: <discord.ext.commands.context.Context object at 0x03B2ED10>
```

Why are all the results the same `<discord.ext.commands.context.Context object>` while getting different `mes`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [`Context`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context) object is always the first parameter passed to a command.
See the [documentation for the commands extension](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html).

This is now true regardless of `pass_context`, which is syntax from a version of discord.py, v0.16, that isn't supported anymore. See [the guide for migrating to v1](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html), specifically the [Context Changes section](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html#context-changes).

Note, a `Context` converter also doesn't make much sense and isn't defined by discord.py.

Answer (score 0):

arguments of `on_command_error()` are context and exception **in order**.

```py
@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx: commands.Context, exception: Exception):
    print(f"Error occured - {type(exception).__name__} : {exception}")
```